# How to start Apache Tomcat the same way Eclipse does from command line?

Tags: eclipse, windows, batch-file, command-line, tomcat7

How can we use a command line command (or script), on Windows, to restart Apache Tomcat on debug mode at the same way Eclipse IDE does (clicking on a button at the Servers view)?

The command (or script) should contain all arguments and parameters Eclipse actually do when we click at the restart button.

The motivation for this is I would like to create a global shortcut (like F12, for example) to restart Apache Tomcat on debug mode.

Comment: Not sure I've understood. Do you want to press e.g. F12 and then Eclipse, which is already up, starts apache tomcat in debug mode? Or do you want to press F12 and then tomcat starts outside of eclipse? I guess it is the first one... I would not do it through the command line, I would use eclipse mechanisms, something like [this link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_my_action%3F). Just a pointer, I would not know how to do it, but I'm sure there's people around who will. Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, both will we nice to me, the first one is better. I and already done something similar, but I necessarily need to click on Servers View and then click F12. I would like click F12 wherever I am on Eclipse Tomcat starts with debuggin, or, if its not possible, I would like click F12 wherever I am on Windows and Tomcat start in debug the same way it starts on Eclipse.

Comment: So, as I said, the 1st is feasible but I cannot help you further than the link I posted, sorry. As for starting tomcat from the command line, it is reasonably easy: you download tomcat as a zip and install it in a directory of your machine, and start it as `catalina.bat jpda run`. You need to put your `war` in tomcat's `webapp` directory and every time you change your `war` you need to clenup both `webapp` and `work` dirs.